# Finite order polynomial convergence to fraction

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, laurent-series

Happy holidays!

So suppose that I have a finite order polynomial expressed as: $$f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^i$$
where $a_i \in \mathbb{R}$. The roots of $f(x)$ can be real or complex. Can $f(x)$ be represented as a ratio of polynomials of infinite order, i.e,
$$f(x) = \frac{\sum_{i=0}^\infty c_ix^i}{\sum_{i=0}^\infty b_ix^i}$$
with $\{b_i,c_i\} \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: “Polynomials of infinite order” are power series. You can express every polynomial $f$ as $\frac{f(z)e^z}{e^z}$ and substitute $e^z$ by its power series ...

Answer (score 0):

You are essentially asking that whether for a given a finite order polynomial  $f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^i$ there exists infinite polynomial sums $(\sum_{i=0}^\infty b_ix^i) \neq 0$ and $(\sum_{i=0}^\infty c_ix^i)$ such that $$f(x)(\sum_{i=0}^\infty b_ix^i) = (\sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^i)(\sum_{i=0}^\infty b_ix^i) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty c_ix^i$$ or not, where $a_i, b_i,c_i \in \mathbb{R}$.

It obviously does. Take any non-zero infinite order polynomial $b(x) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty b_ix^i$. Then, $$f(x)(\sum_{i=0}^\infty b_ix^i) = (\sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^i)(\sum_{i=0}^\infty b_ix^i) \\ = a_0b_0 + (a_0b_1+a_1b_0)x + (a_0b_2+a_1b_1+a_2b_0)x^2 + \dots + (\sum_{k=0}^n a_kb_{n-k})x^n + \dots \\= \sum_{i=0}^\infty c_ix^i \ \ \text{where,} \ c_n = \sum_{k=0}^n a_kb_{n-k} \in R$$

$$\text{So,} \ \ \ \fbox{$f(x) = \frac{\sum_{i=0}^\infty c_ix^i}{\sum_{i=0}^\infty b_ix^i}$} \ \ \text{with} \ b_i,c_i \in \mathbb{R}.$$